# How can I delete a git alias?

Tags: git, alias

I'm learning to work with git, and I tried to set some aliases like this:

```
git config --global alias.trololo 'status'
```

So now when I type `git trololo` it works like `git status`.

Now trololo alias is not needed. How can I correctly delete it?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can try `--unset` in [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
git config --global --unset alias.trololo
```

I find it safer than editing directly the config file (`git config --global --edit`)

Comment: In addition to being the correct way to do this, this solution has the benefit of working for local and system aliases, as well as global aliases, provided you use the appropriate flag (`--local`, etc).

Answer (score 39):

In case someone has multiple values for the same alias and has got that:

```
$ git config --global --unset alias.trololo
warning: alias.trololo has multiple values
```

Use `--unset-all`

```
git config --global --unset-all alias.trololo
```

Answer (score 18):

Or just:

```
vim ~/.gitconfig
```

And delete the alias lines.

Comment: is this fragile to implementation changes?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley Yes. And just provide another way. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can remove it by deleting that line from the configuration file or you can try this:

```
git config --global --unset alias.YourAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove it in your global settings files by:

- Running `git config --global -e`
- Locate the alias in the opend global settings file.
- Erase it, and save the file.