# git log alias with parameters not woring

Tags: git-alias

I have this alias for git setup which is working.

```
git config alias.migrations 'log'
```

But when I add a parameter its not working correctly.

```
git config alias.migrations 'log -- **/Migrations/'
```

Any ideas?

So when I do

```
git log -- **/Migrations/
```

I get all logs showing changes from Migrations folder.

But when I use the alias, I dot see any output, neither does it give any error.

[image: git log alias]

The image above also shows the config file inside of .git folder.

Answer (score 0):

Getting things working is a pain to my dumb brain.

Ok, so here is how I settled it, using a function. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418367/1977871).

```
git config alias.migrations '!fmigrations() { git log -- **/Migrations/; }; fmigrations'
```

A couple of more cents.

To list all of the aliases. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066424/1977871)

```
git config --get-regexp alias
```

To remove an alias. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23512420/1977871)

```
git config --unset alias.migrations
```

Finally, you may want to add --global flag if you want that alias to be global. So the commands would be

```
git config --global alias.migrations '!fmigrations() { git log -- **/Migrations/; }; fmigrations'
git config --global --unset alias.migrations
```